# Exist a constant that only depends of a power and dimension that bounds the euclidean norm.

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces, boundary-value-problem

I have this problem but I don't know how to solve it.

Considering the Euclidean norm |x|, in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $a>0$, prove there exist $c>0$ depending only of $n$ and $a$ such that:
$$c^{-1}(|x_1|^a+\dots+|x_n|^a) \leq |x|^a \leq c(|x_1|^a+\dots+|x_n|^a). $$
I tried to use the AM-GM inequality but I didn't go anywhere. Also, this exercise is after the section of Fubini's Theorem in my book of Lebesgue Measure, but I don't know how to use that. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Take everything and rise it to the power $1/\alpha$. Then use that all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional spaces. Or look up a proof for that statement.

Comment: I really want a way that doesn't use that all norms are equivalent if it is possible.

Comment: Essentially proving this statement is proving that the $L_{\alpha}$ norm is equivalent to $L_2$ norm. So I suggest you try to find a prove which does this. If I am correct one inequality is probably easy and one is more difficult but that is just me trying to remember it.

Comment: For example, first part of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890009/all-norms-of-mathbb-rn-are-equivalent

Comment: @StanTendijck You may notice that, for $a\in(0,1)$, this is **not** a norm you're getting.

Comment: Ah yes you're right